# using CANalyzer libraries in Microsoft visual studios

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, capl, canalyzer

I'm trying to use CAPL/CANalyzer functions in visual studio. I found some information on how to implement it in the CAPL help menu, but when i try I can't seem to get it to work. Is there any online resource on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

the [Vector knowledgebase](https://kb.vector.com/) is online

Think the best way to start is to open *CANalyzer Sample Configurations* Folder in My Documents and to find a lot of samples for specific aspects.

There is also lot of information on CANalyzer help-pages, for example in:

```
.NET Programming » Notes for Advanced Users
```

you can find the reference to which assemblies do you need

If you have a specific problem please provide more information: what you trying to do, what is your expectation and what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible with CANalyzer. You will need CANoe for this.
Take a look at the [feature matrix](https://vector.com/portal/medien/cmc/datasheets/CANoe_CANalyzer_FeatureMatrix_DataSheet_EN.pdf). On side 6 it says that .net is only available in CANoe. Additionally I think that calls from .net to CAPL are only available for test modules and test units.